# Transparent Image in Textview DrawableTop Not Showing Properly

Tags: android, textview

The images shown below are in PNG format, with transparent background.

I used a TextView per item which consists of a DrawableTop image and Text. I wanted my image to be transparent but it is not working properly. I tried alpha method for transparency but the entire TextView will lighten. I wanted just the image, not the entire TextView.

By the way, I used TextView instead of a LinearLayout per item consisting of an ImageView and TextView because the IDE prompted me with a warning and I was advised not to have any warning in my code.

I have the following code in Android:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/marketBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/unselected_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/market_icon_0"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="1dp"
        android:paddingRight="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/task_bar_lbl_market"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
```

I am now confused what to do next. Should there be any help, I will be much grateful! For more info, here's a screen cap of this bug:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Button instead of TextView :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/marketBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/show"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/name"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:background="@drawable/unselected_button"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/market_icon_0"
        android:text="@string/task_bar_lbl_market"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but still I'm facing the same error.

Comment: Is your image having transparent background?

Answer (score 0):

You must combine background and drawableTop style.

You don't need image transparent for background.
You can used #ARGB [int alpha, int red, int green, int blue]

```
    <item name="android:background">#0000</item>
    <item name="android:drawableTop">@drawable/btn_setting</item>
```